# Draft preview and customize permission problems on multisite main site

Tags: multisite, nonce

So I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while now and it feels like I've tried everything. I would love for some support here.

### Setup

- A WordPress multisite with [Bedrock structure](https://roots.io/bedrock/)
- PHP 7.3.17 (local) and PHP 7.2.24 (live)
- Apache
- Themes: Custom "mother theme" and child themes for each site.

### Problem

The first site among the multisites seem to have some kind of structural problem. The other sites works just fine.

When previewing drafts on posts and pages the user (including superadmin) gets a message: `Sorry, you are not allowed to preview drafts`. I've tracked it down to `_show_post_preview()` in `wp-includes/revision.php` and it seems like the nonce check fails.

A similar problem occurs when customizing the site. When trying to save changes you get: `You need a higher level of permission. Sorry, you are not allowed to customize this site.` This error is thrown in `wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js` in function `cheatin()` which seem to be used when the nonce is off.

### What I've tried (no luck)

- Deactivating all plugins
- Switching to one of the other child themes that works on their sites
- Clear WordPress cache
- Clear browser cache
- Creating the nonce by myself in the `preview_post_link` filter.
- Double, triple check `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` (in Bedrock: `config/application.php`)

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Good work tracking it down to the nonce check in _show_post_preview. I'd probably debug that first: can you try tracing out the strings that it's using to construct and validate the nonce? e.g. just trace out the arguments in wp_hash? And if there's no obvious difference there, maybe trace out the salt too - there's no chance it's getting different salts from different wp-configs is there?

Comment: @Rup Hm. I don't see anything odd about preview_nonce or the preview_id. The expected nonce and its arguments passed to the wp_hash looks ok. But when comparing expected to the nonce it fails. Could it be some kind of timing that's out of sync? The salts and nonce keys are shared by the other sites on the multisite so they seem ok as well.

Comment: The nonce comparison is just the wp_hash - if you're hashing exactly the same things when you create the nonce as you are when you are verifying it, and the keys are the same, then it should just work. The timing bit is the first component of the string hashed, which is a counter of 12-hour periods, and a nonce should be valid for 12-24 hours.

Comment: @Rup Oh. Yes, they are different on my main site. On the other sites they are the same. But how do I get them to be the same? Any ideas where to look?

Comment: @Rup I found something. The wp_get_session_token returns nothing. I think we've found the bad guy here.

Comment: Hey @Rup. Thanks for holding my hand through this one. I've finally found it. I had `define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');` in my config that seem to have messed it up.